# Periodogram() function producing integer overflow

Tags: r

I used the periodogram() in R and I got the error message.

> Warning message: object@samp.rate * seq(1, width/2) : NAs produced by
>   integer overflow

Here is the code I executed. And I'm using the tuneR package.

```
waveform <- readWave(test.wav)
maxFreq <- sampleRate/2
minFreq <- 0
periodogram(waveform, width = 131072, overlap = 0, starts = NULL, ends = NULL, taper = 0, normalize = TRUE, frqRange = c(minFreq, maxFreq))
```

How do I resolve this.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: Just edited my question. Sorry i used the tuneR package.

Comment: Try a smaller `width` argument to see if that's what causes your overflow (I bet it is).  BTW - that is a *Warning*, not an *Error* message, meaning your code doesn't crash  but you've lost some data due to the overflow (large integers) being replaced with `NA` .